# Basis functions and positive definiteness

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose I have a set of functions $g_i(x)$ which form a basis on some interval $[a,b]$. My question is whether the matrix
$$
A_{ij} = \int_a^b g_i(x) g_j(x) dx
$$
is positive definite?

My approach so far is to consider a function $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,
$$
f(x) = \sum_i c_i g_i(x) = c^T g(x)
$$
Then we have:
\begin{align}
0 &\le \int_a^b |f(x)|^2 dx \\
& = \int_a^b c^T g(x) g(x)^T c dx \\
&= c^T \left( \int_a^b g(x) g(x)^T dx \right) c \\
&= c^T A c
\end{align}
This shows that $A$ is postive semi-definite.

But I wonder if it is correct to argue that $\int_a^b |f(x)|^2 dx$ is equal to $0$ only if $c = 0$, because otherwise if $c \ne 0$, then that implies that the $g_i(x) = 0$ for all $i$ and all $x$, contradicting the assumption that $g_i(x)$ is a basis. Is that correct reasoning?

As a followup question, consider the matrix
$$
B_{ij} = \int_a^b g'_i(x) g'_j(x) dx
$$
This matrix is positive semi-definite by the same reasoning above, but is it also positive definite? If the argument above is correct, I don't think it applies to the matrix $B$, because if $g_i(x)$ forms a basis on $[a,b]$, that doesn't necessarily mean that $g'_i(x)$ is also a basis?

**So the question is whether $A$ and/or $B$ are positive definite matrices?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sum c_ic_j \int_a^{b} g_i'(x)g_j'(x)\, dx=\int_a^{b}\sum c_ic_j \int_a^{b} g_i'(x)g_j'(x)\, dx=\int_a^{b} |\sum c_ig_i'(x)|^{2}\, dx \geq 0$. So $B$ is non-negative definite. But $\sum c_ic_j \int_a^{b} g_i'(x)g_j'(x)\, dx=0$ only implies $\sum c_ig_i=c$ for some constant $c$ and $B$ need not be positive definite.

For a counter-example take $h_1(x)=x$ and $h_2(x)=3x-2$.  Normalize these two orthogonal functions get an orthonormal set $\{g_1,g_2\}$. You can extend this to an orthonormal basis for $L^{2}[0,1]$. Now check that $g_1-\frac 2 {\sqrt 3} g_2$ is a non-zero constant. This provides a counter-example.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense

Comment: In your example, $g_1(x)$ and $g_2(x)$ are not even independent basis functions. I am not sure if it even proves that B can be 0.

Comment: @stackoverblown Thank you for your comment. I have edited my answer.